# Creating a link from another column in a SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a SharePoint 2010 List that contains an email address field which has been created by using the person who added the list items username and tagging on our email domain name.

I have created a new column in the list to create a mailto link:

```
="<a href='mailto:[Email]'>Email Me</a>"
```

This displays as code and works as a hyperlink, the problem I have is that the mailto link doesn't recognise the content of the [Email] address field, it returns:

```
mailto:[Email]
```

And when clicked it adds [Email] into the to field in Outlook rather than the email address in the field.

Am I doing something wrong? any help or advice would be gratefully received.

It's worth noting I don't have access to SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the actual column name to a single string. You need to split the text string and add the column in between using `&`.

```
="<a href='mailto:"&[Email]&"'>Email Me</a>"
```